# How to implement infinite swipable week view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently working on an app with class schedule. I need to implement a swipable week view just like in Apple's "Calendar" app. There is no built-in solution for this in SwiftUI (Maybe I didn't find it), so I used [SwiftUIPager](https://github.com/fermoya/SwiftUIPager) library. It kinda works, but I have to provide it an array of elements. Then Pager use this elements to create pages. This does not suit me, so I decided to dynamically add elements of the array when I approach its border.

```swift
struct WeekObserverView: View {
    
    let vm: WeekObserverViewModel = WeekObserverViewModel()
    let OnDayChanged: (Date)->Any
    
    @State private var selectedDay = Date()
    @State private var currentPage = Page.withIndex(2)
    @State private var data = Array(-2..<3)
    @State private var disableButtons = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                Pager(page: currentPage,
                      data: data,
                      id: \.self) {
                    self.generateWeekView($0)
                }
                      .singlePagination(ratio: 0.5, sensitivity: .high)
                      .onPageWillChange({ (page) in
                          withAnimation {
                  //Moving forward or backward a week
                              selectedDay = selectedDay + TimeInterval(604800) * Double((page - currentPage.index))
                          }
                          _ = OnDayChanged(selectedDay)
                      })
                      .onPageChanged({
                          page in
                                                  //Adding new weeks when we approach the boundaries of the array
                          if page == 1 {
                              let newData = (1...5).map { data.first! - $0 }.reversed()
                              withAnimation {
                                  currentPage.update(.move(increment: newData.count))
                                  data.insert(contentsOf: newData, at: 0)
                              }
                          } else if page == self.data.count - 2 {
                              guard let last = self.data.last else { return }
                              let newData = (1...5).map { last + $0 }
                              withAnimation {
                                  data.append(contentsOf: newData)
                              }
                          }
                          disableButtons = false
                      })
                      .onDraggingBegan({
                          disableButtons = true
                      })
                      .pagingPriority(.simultaneous)
                      .frame(height: 48)
                Capsule()
                    .frame(width: 32, height: 6)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("TransparetPurple"))
                    .padding(4)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color("AccentBlue"))
            //Spacer()
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I adding element to the front of array Pager loses current page and goes to the next page on the left.

I tried to add one extra page to the index, but it didn't work

```swift
currentPage.update(.move(increment: newData.count + 1))
```

Maybe there is a more simple solution without providing an array? I want Pager to just give me the offset from first loaded page.

Comment: Have a look at highly stared Calendar library [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar). you can use if for infinite Calendar view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this and checked an example called `InfiniteExampleView` included in the git project for SwiftUIPager.

I noticed how they are able to add items to the array dynamically both in front of the current items and behind them.

I can't test your code completely since there are some missing parts to make it run the way you run it, but it seems when they insert in front of current items they update the page index as well and I don't see you do that in your code.

This is the code from the example:

```
if page == 1 {
   let newData = (1...5).map { data1.first! - $0 }.reversed()
   withAnimation {
       page1.index += newData.count //<-- this line
       data1.insert(contentsOf: newData, at: 0)
       isPresented.toggle()
   }
}
```

this is your code under the `withAnimation` part of if statement `page==1`:

```
currentPage.update(.move(increment: newData.count))
data.insert(contentsOf: newData, at: 0)
```

So maybe adding a line to change the index helps fix this. If not, please provide a more complete example to make it possible to debug it more easily.

Comment: Thank you for you answer) Isn’t .update(…) the same as .index = …?

Comment: It's not exactly the same, it updates the index but also: "Will update `Page` accordingly and trigger `objectWillChange` If you do not wish to trigger an update because you want to take control of the update, set `index` direclty." Doesn't this mean the index is changed and a ui update is triggered and then after that you lengthen the array when calling insert? Maybe it's a better idea to insert the data and then call the update function afterwards. But like I mentioned, there are other parts in your code that are not included, so they could also be causing some undesired behavior.